# MySQL 8 order by created_at out of sort memory error 1038

Tags: mysql, out-of-memory, mysql-8.0

I just recently upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.3. The update process seems to have gone well. No significant problems noted in mysqld.log. I was able to connect fine to my database.

But when I try to perform a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error (1038): Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
```

I've checked in `my.ini` and I have `sort_buffer_size=1M`, the same as I had in MySQL 5.7.

The `created_at` column is a nullable `timestamp` with no index. The table is small, <90 rows. I never had this problem with MySQL 5.7, not even with tables with hundreds of thousands of rows.

What could be wrong?

The `EXPLAIN` of the query:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | mytable | \N | ALL | \N | \N | \N | \N | 31 | 100.00 | Using filesort |

I noticed the row count is way below the actual number of rows in the table. I tried `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and now the `EXPLAIN` shows 43 rows, still about half of the real number.

I did a dump of the database before upgrading MySQL so I tried dropping and restoring that table from the dump in case somehow it was corrupted. No change.

What else should I do in this case?

Here's my `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `relation_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `request_data` JSON NOT NULL,
    `response_data` JSON NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `filename` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `remote_key` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `relation_id` (`relation_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't think this is an issue of adding an index to `created_at` as I have tables with hundreds of thousands of rows that sort just fine without that index.

Could it have something to do with the 2 JSON columns? Some of those responses I save have lots of data.

**More info:**

The size of the largest JSON field is 430 kb.

`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mytable'`:

| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mytable | InnoDB | 10 | Dynamic | 44 | 131444 | 5783552 | 0 | 0 | 4194304 | \N | 2021-04-24 15:21:00 | 2021-04-24 14:33:36 | \N | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | \N |  |  |

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1000;`:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "360.21"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "43.00"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "mytable",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 43,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 43,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "312.91",
          "eval_cost": "4.30",
          "prefix_cost": "317.21",
          "data_read_per_join": "173K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "relation_id",
          "request_data",
          "response_data",
          "filename",
          "remote_key",
          "created_at",
          "updated_at"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This happens when the column `created_at` is not indexed. Because of this the complete table needs to be read, and sorted, which could use more than 1M.   It also seems related to this [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103225)

Comment: Does your table have indexes? Can you show output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable\G` ?

Comment: True, putting an index on `created_at` helps, but what I don't understand is why I could sort without the index in MySQL 5.7 and not in MySQL 8.0. Does MySQL 8.0 really perform that much worse than MySQL 5.7? 87 rows of `created_at` data is far less than 1M. I feel like there's something else I'm missing here. With MySQL 5.7 I never ran out sort memory even on giant tables. It just took a long time to sort without indexes, but it always worked. So I'm confused why I'm getting this error now.

Comment: No, something else is wrong here. I just tested with a table that has 300k+ rows, no index on `created_at`, and it loaded in less than a second. Adding the index to `created_at` isn't the answer here. But I'll post my `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: [Sort buffer space is now used more effectively, so that filesorts need not flush to disk as early or
often as with fixed-length sort keys. This means that more data can be sorted in memory, avoiding
unnecessary disk access.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/mysql-8.0-en.pdf)  This could explain the difference between 5.7 and 8.0

Comment: Interesting! Based on your comment I've been reading more about other people with this problem and I found this in [release notes for MySQL 8.0.20](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-20.html):

"One effect of this enhancement is that it is now possible for Out of memory errors to occur when trying to sort rows containing very large (multi-megabtye) JSON or GEOMETRY column values if the sort buffers are of insufficient size; this can be compensated for in the usual fashion by increasing the value of the sort_buffer_size system variable."

Comment: I was not searching long enough to find that note... 

Comment: Strange.  Let's look at some more things:  `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE mytable;`;  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` ;  And the Optimizer trace.

Comment: Meanwhile, file a bug report; this should never happen.  bugs.mysql.com

Comment: How long is the longest JSON string in the table.  This could be a factor.

Comment: What value do you have for `innodb_sort_buffer_size`?  (Note the "innodb_".)

Comment: Perhaps fixed in MariaDB-10.5.7: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24015

Comment: (Separate issue):  Why have two unique keys?

Comment: @RickJames what do you mean 2 unique keys? One's the table's primary key and the `relation_id` is actually an ID from another database that should be unique. Also, I added the info you requested. and the `innodb_sort_buffer_size` is 134217728. I might report it but from the release notes I mentioned above it sounds like this is a known issue and is now expected.

Comment: So from what I've gathered, if I understand it correctly the issue is something like this?: Since `created_at` doesn't have an index MySQL does a `filesort`. Due to a change in version `8.0.20` now it packs JSON data into the sorting data instead of omitting it like a `LONGBLOB` like it did in previous versions. That means my table with 5MB-worth of data doesn't fit in the 1MB buffer... So the solution in this case is to add the index to `created_at` so that it doesn't do the `filesort` and include the JSON data... if I understand everything correctly??

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, Unique in MySQL.  Hence, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: I think the error message is unacceptable when it has two alternatives -- (1) use statistics to predict that 1038 could occur, or (2) abort from using the sort buffer and do the sort the other way.

Comment: @Chris - I added to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103225 .  You might want to Subscribe and say "me to".

Comment: @RickJames Ok, thanks. I'll see if I can obfuscate the sensitive data in my table so I can send it to them so they have a reproducible example.

Comment: Ok, I created a bug report for it: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103465

Comment: So quick update, the MySQL team responded and closed the bug report basically saying: "This is how MySQL works now. Deal with it. Increase the sort buffer size as much as you need so that the problem doesn't occur."